# How to set active content in dockpanel suite

Tags: c#, .net, dockpanel-suite

I have a list of object. 
I am using the WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite to display each object in the list in a different window.
I want to be able to set the active window in the dockPanel so the active window will be the one I selected in the object list.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Hey @Marc.O,
Have you find any solutions for it?

Comment: @VishalKiri The link in the answer I accepted did the trick for me.

Comment: I didn't find any solutions  for this links.

Comment: WhateverDockContent.Activate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please first check out our FAQ list,

https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues?labels=faq+candidate&page=1&state=closed

You can see that #204 is exactly what you should read,

https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/204

Comment: Sorry I did look in the FAQ but I must have mist it. Thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: Sometimes contents might not yet arrive in FAQ section ASAP. So except FAQ, you might also read closed questions, https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues?labels=question&page=1&state=closed They are the questions previous discussed by the community.

Comment: Hey @LexLi,
I have search around on it, but it's still not working.